# How to run a julia chunk in RMarkdown

Tags: r, julia, r-markdown

I am trying to run a Julia chunk in RMarkdown.  I am using the package `JuliaCall`.  Here are the steps I've completed:

1. Downloaded Julia
2. Installed `JuliaCall`
3. Run the code `julia_setup(JULIA_HOME = "C:/Users/James/Documents/Julia 1.5.1/bin")`
4. Run `julia <- julia_setup()`

Here is a minimal example of my RMarkdown file:

````
---
title: "julia_eg"
author: "James"
date: "9/23/2020"
output: html_document
---

```{r setup, include=FALSE}
knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo = TRUE)
```

this is a julia example

```{julia}
a = sqrt(17)
a
```
````

When I try and knit this, it tells me it cannot find Julia - I get this error:

`Error in julia_locate(JULIA_HOME) : Can not find the Julia installation in the default installation path 'C:\Users\James\AppData\Local' Calls: <Anonymous> ... withVisible -> eval -> julia_setup -> julia_locate`

So clearly my running of `julia_setup` in step 3 above didn't have the desired effect - even though it did run this for sometime and told me that it had completed that task.

Is there a more straightforward way of getting it to find Julia?

Comment: Add the setup In the initial chunk so markdown is aware of it.

Comment: thanks - super obvious, I should have realized. It works.  Do you want to post as an answer ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Rmarkdown is only aware of any code that is run in the immediate session, to avoid creating documents that will be impossible to compile by itself.

As such you'll have to add the code to the initial code chunk

````
```{r setup, include=FALSE}
knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo = TRUE)
Julia_setup(JULIA_HOME = "C:/Users/James/Documents/Julia 1.5.1/bin")
julia <- julia_setup()
```
````